# How do I add the content type token in the page title?

Tags: 7

I have installed the Page Title module. What I want to achieve is to add the content type token as page title. I tried to change the pattern in the configuration of the Page Title module, but the tokens appear as they are: "[current-page:page-title], [field_glossary_transliterations] - [field_glossary_meaning] | [site:name]."

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Simply insert the [node:content-type] token.

Longer answer:

The [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) module modifies the title that appears in the `<title>` tag (which also displays in your [browser's title bar](http://drupal.org/files/images/page-title.png). Just to clarify, this is separate from an individual node's title.

In the module configuration page, you will only see the raw token names displayed. The Page Title module will convert those tokens to human readable values on an actual node or "page". View the source of one of your nodes and check the `<title>` tag to see the actual values.

This module relies on the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module in order to operate.

You can also get the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module (and enable the Entity Tokens submodule) to get even more tokens that weren't picked up before.

Also: Be aware that the project maintainer has identified an issue with Fusion based themes. If your site falls into that category, temporarily switch to another theme such as Bartik to test out the page title module.

Comment: Yes, I found that at the bottom of Page-Title-module there is a list of all available tokens, including all the custom fields created for content-types as well.

Comment: so ... did you check to see if the <title> tag in the HTML has changed? Or maybe you have a different / new problem, in which case you should update your question.

Comment: It works perfectly. Heres what I did:
[current-page:page-title] - [node:field_geography_capital] - [node:field_geography_currency] - [node:field_geography_languages]
Since the title was getting too long, I left out the site name from this particular content-type.

Comment: There is something to be aware of here is that if you leave a field blank, the field name itself shows up in the title. Any Idea how to avoid that?

Comment: Hmm, that might be something for the module issue queue: http://drupal.org/project/issues/page_title?categories=All Also, if I answered your question you can click the checkmark to mark it as answered.

Comment: I could not locate the link on this page to mark this as 'answered'. Where is it?